# R: Is the Kolmogorov–Smirnov test capable of comparing samples?

Tags: r

Does anyone know whether the Kolmogorov–Smirnov test is capable of comparing samples?

According to the definition of the Kolmogorov–Smirnov test, it is a nonparametric test for the equality of continuous, one-dimensional probability distributions that can be used to compare a sample with a reference probability distribution (one-sample K–S test), or **to compare two samples**.

Does anyone know if the code in R is able to compare samples and is not just limited to comparison to a theoretical distribution? And if so, could you please give an example?

Answer (score 7):

Examples are to be found in the [help files of ks.test](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/ks.test.html). (`?ks.test`) :

```
Usage

ks.test(x, y, ...,
        alternative = c("two.sided", "less", "greater"),
        exact = NULL)

Arguments

x   a numeric vector of data values.
y   either a numeric vector of data values, or a character string naming a ...
```

Tells you how to do it, and :

```
Examples

require(graphics)

x <- rnorm(50)
y <- runif(30)
# Do x and y come from the same distribution?
ks.test(x, y)
```

is the first example in the help files. Please read them before asking. They're there for a reason, and that reason is not "entertainment of the R-development team".

Comment: Thank you Joris, I am new to R.. I had the impression that searching in google for R help
http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/truncgof/html/ks.test.html
 would give me the same as R itself, and I understand that it is not always the same. Thank you anyway!

Comment: @user573347 : what you have there, is the ks.test function in the truncgof package, not in the base packages. It's advisable to always look within R first, as not all help files on the net are updated to the latest version, and confusion about packages might exist. Cheers